# How to find the angle between two coordinatess in mapbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I was working on mapbox and on the basis of my current `latlong`, a random distance of `226mt` and a random degree of `179 degrees`, I calculated another latlong as follows.

```
function findpos(){
    var ptt = new mapboxgl.LngLat(latitude,longitude);
    var ptt2 = destinationPoint(179.85, 0.226, ptt);

    return ptt2;
}


  Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
   return this * Math.PI / 180;
}

Number.prototype.toDeg = function() {
   return this * 180 / Math.PI;
}

function destinationPoint(brng, dist, pointA) {
   dist = dist / 6378.1;
   brng = brng.toRad();

   var lat1 = pointA.lat.toRad(), lon1 = pointA.lng.toRad();

   var lat2 = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(dist) +
                        Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(dist) * Math.cos(brng));

   var lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng) * Math.sin(dist) *
                                Math.cos(lat1),
                                Math.cos(dist) - Math.sin(lat1) *
                                Math.sin(lat2));

   if (isNaN(lat2) || isNaN(lon2)) return null;
   console.log("des ",lon2,lat2);
   return new mapboxgl.LngLat(lat2.toDeg(), lon2.toDeg());
}
```

It was okay till this point.But Now I wanted to find the angle or bearing between two latlongs and found this

```
// Converts from degrees to radians.
function toRadians(degrees) {
  return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
};

// Converts from radians to degrees.
function toDegrees(radians) {
  return radians * 180 / Math.PI;
}


function bearing(startLat, startLng, destLat, destLng){
  startLat = toRadians(startLat);
  startLng = toRadians(startLng);
  destLat = toRadians(destLat);
  destLng = toRadians(destLng);

  y = Math.sin(destLng - startLng) * Math.cos(destLat);
  x = Math.cos(startLat) * Math.sin(destLat) -
        Math.sin(startLat) * Math.cos(destLat) * Math.cos(destLng - startLng);
  brng = Math.atan2(y, x);
  brng = toDegrees(brng);
  return (brng + 360) % 360;
//  return brng;
}
```

It calculates a degree and gives a result. But when i decided to double check this function by putting the already calculated latlongs by the function `findpos()` above, i should have got the answer as `179.85 degrees`, but instead I get the angle as `270 degree`.

Which part of the code is correct? I have created a working example [here](https://codepen.io/MusketeerHo/pen/LYpJJKL), and have logged the values in the console. Can anyone help me out here please?

Comment: No idea where you're getting these calculations from; all you need is `const y = destLat - startLat; const x = destLng - startLng;` then `return toDegrees(Math.atan2(y, x));`, result: 179.32707567621796 (I also created a proper pen: https://codepen.io/khrismuc/pen/PoPdyOg?editors=0010)

Comment: @ChrisG turns out you are right . Many thanks. If you can write that as answer I will accept it as the annswer.

Comment: Wait, sorry, you were using the formula for a sphere. I get 89 degrees when I do that. However for short distances the simple formula works fine.

Comment: @ChrisG for about how much distance this formula works fine ? and will this work fine in any part of the world for the said short distance?

Comment: I'd say it's close enough for distances below 500km maybe? You should ideally also be close the equator; near the poles the error gets bigger, because the longitude lines deviate further and further from a square grid. If we're talking bigger distances, there's also the fun wrinkle that the bearing will constantly change, this is why the formula only calculates the initial bearing. So it really depends on what exactly you need this for.

Comment: @ChrisG got your point , many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `mapboxgl.LngLat()` function. The function name already contains the order in which it expects you to pass longitude and latitude -- > first longitude then latitude. You are passing first latitude then longitude. This will definitely cause a problem.

Your code:

```js
function findpos(){
    var ptt = new mapboxgl.LngLat(latitude,longitude);
    var ptt2 = destinationPoint(179.85, 0.226, ptt);

    return ptt2;
}
```

Try this:

```js
function findpos(){
    var ptt = new mapboxgl.LngLat(longitude,latitude);
    var ptt2 = destinationPoint(179.85, 0.226, ptt);

    return ptt2;
}
```

Similar for this part of your code:

```js
return new mapboxgl.LngLat(lat2.toDeg(), lon2.toDeg());
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on [Turf](http://turfjs.org/) documentation

It provide's two different methods. You can try :

http://turfjs.org/docs/#bearing

http://turfjs.org/docs/#rhumbBearing